# Why selector for custom ESLint rule fails on AST?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, eslint

I have AST:

https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/4876725d1019dd6f4aec8f2f120ec56d/2f8f40858b5524b6b6c9dbd427dc86e68e902a50

And want to restrict string literals as arguments of function `classname`.

I have created rule:

```
create: function(context) {
    return {
        "CallExpression": function (node) {
          const argument = node.arguments && node.arguments.find(element => (element.type === 'Literal'));
          if (
            (node.callee.name === 'classnames')
            && ( argument !== undefined)
          ){
            context.report({
              node,
              message: "You should use css modules instead of {{identifier}}",
              data: {
                identifier: argument.raw,
              }
            })
          }
        },
    }
}
```

which is fine, but if I try to use more complex selector, like

```
create: function(context) {
    return {
        "CallExpression[callee.name='classnames']": function (node) {...}
    }
}
```

it's fail miserably. I think I got [selectors](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/selectors) idea somehow wrong. May you clarify how to use them properly?

Also is there any way to make query inside function? 
For example check if package 'classnames' was imported, get name of variable where it was imported and then query ast for CallExpression with this specific name.

Comment: Have you found any answers to your questions? Especially, "any way to make query inside function"?